# Do I need to use ADO when connecting to Active Directory with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, active-directory, dao

I need to query Active Directory and build my MS Access database using the results. I found some code [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee156501.aspx). As you can see, part of this code is creating an `ADODB.Connection` object. Is this the only method for connecting to AD? Is it possible to use DAO objects?

I've never taken any courses on databases so forgive me if this question makes no sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see part of this code is creating an ADODB.connection object. Is this the only method for connecting to AD? Is it possible to use DAO objects?

Personally I wouldn't recommend trying to use DAO to query AD. DAO works very well to manipulate *Access database tables from within Access itself*, but for Access VBA code to manipulate any data source that isn't...

- a local Access table or
- an Access "linked table"

...I would recommend using ADO. You can use the code samples in the article you cited, and if you run into any difficulties you will be much more likely to receive meaningful assistance.

Comment: How do you suggest inserting all the records returned from an AD query into a table in the database? i can only think of looping through the recordset and inserting each record.

Comment: @McAngus Yes, that's probably what you'll have to do since (1) the AD queries don't appear to use SQL, and (2) they would be on a different connection from the one that would manipulate the Access table(s), anyway.